# Angular 'Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.'

Tags: html, angular, spring-boot

I'm creating an Angular app which shows list of projects and list of users from postgresql database, but I'm having issues with showing list of users in html.
The problem is that Angular is considering my array as an object no matter what I do.
The same code worked for projects but didn't work for users.

This is my service:

```
    import { environment } from "../../../environments/environment";
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { Projet } from '../modele/projet.model';
    import { Test } from '../modele/test.model';
    import { HttpParams,HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
    import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
    import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
    import { User } from '../modele/user.model';
    import { Financement } from '../modele/financement.model';
        
    @Injectable()
    export class WebService {
            
        constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }
            
        serverUrl: string = "http://localhost:8080/"
              
        get(url: string): Observable<any> {
            return this.httpClient.get(this.serverUrl + url);
        }
    }
```

The component :

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { User } from '../../shared/modele/user.model';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { WebService } from '../../shared/sevices/web.service';
    import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators, Form } from '@angular/forms';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-show-users',
      templateUrl: './show-users.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./show-users.component.scss']
    })

    export class ShowUsersComponent implements OnInit {
    
        ngOnInit(): void {
          this.getData();
        }
        usersList: Array<User>
        user: User 
        myForm: FormGroup;
      
        constructor(private webService: WebService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder,private router: Router) { }
      
        getData(): void {
          this.webService.get("showUsers").subscribe(res => {
            let response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))
            this.usersList = response.data
      
          })
        }
      }
```

The html :

```
        <tr *ngFor="let user of usersList">
            <td>{{user.name}}</td>            
            <td>{{user.username}}</td>
            <td>{{user.email}}</td>
        </tr>
```

This is the server response :
[server response](https://i.ibb.co/r7y4msM/Sans-titre-1.jpg)

***NB: the EXACT same code worked for the object PROJECT***

Comment: Could you please post the response that you are getting from the rest call ? It seems like there is issue with that only.

Comment: why do you JSON.stringify then JSON.parse on the same object on the same line

Comment: Don't forget to accept and upvote answers that helped you out >_>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make sure that the variable you pass into `*ngFor` is an array. You can make sure of this with `Array.from(v)` and can also strip any keys of an Object that might be sent from the serverside with `Object.values(v)`:

```
this.webService.get("showUsers").subscribe(res => {
  this.usersList = Array.from(Object.values(res.data.body.data));
})
```

Comment: the variable this.usersList is already declared Array

Comment: Doesn't matter what type you declare it as, you still need to sanitize the actual data you receive. TypeScript types are just compile-time checks. There can be only 1 reason why Angular says that it can't do `ngFor` on an object: because it is an object and not an array :p

Comment: I've had this error a couple of times myself, even when the data looked like it was an array in every possible way. Give it a try ;)

Comment: it gives me this error
ERROR TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
    at Function.from (<anonymous>)

Comment: Oh, uhm you're probably not setting the value of `this.usersList` first, my answer might be a bit confusing, I will update

Comment: it works but it gives blank rows inside the HTML table with no data inside them

Comment: it works but it gives blank rows inside the HTML table with no data inside them

Comment: Basic debugging `console.log` the value of `res.data`, `Object.values(res.data)` and `Array.from(Object.values(res.data))` and see where the problem is. If those values are correct then the problem is in your HTML template.

Comment: Your server response shows me that the actual data is in `res.data.body.data`; not `res.data` ;)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have a simple approach, but I spent a lot of time. You could try this:

```js
datas: any;

this.token = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('token'));

this.authService.getData(this.token.id).subscribe(data => { 
    this.datas = data;  
})
```

In the HTML template just use `this.datas.id, this.datas.username` instead of an `*ngFor`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need this code:

```
let response = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res))
this.usersList = response.data
```

simply use:

```
this.userlist = res
```

Youe complete method:

```
this.webService.get("showUsers").subscribe(res => {
  this.userlist = res
});
```

Comment: still same problem , Angular is still considering my array as an object